# C#: Change Windows Theme

Tags: c#, themes

Is there C# code for changing the title bar of windows to "black" or for changing the design of graphical elements? For example, I want to implement the Liza Theme (http://cleodesktop.deviantart.com/art/Liza-Dark-Theme-for-Windows-8-8-1-440279895):
[image: Liza Theme]
in my C# Windows Forms project. I would prefer that the theme works system-wide and I would really appreciate it if anyone can answer.

Comment: You can get a lot more UI customisation ability by using WPF rather than winforms, the difference is phenomenal and I would strongly recommend making the switch. This library http://mahapps.com/ is get for easily getting up and running with a dark theme, it's not your precise Liza theme but it's a starting point

Comment: @lilactiger89 Thanks for your reply! I am considering using WPF in the future, but for the sake of the post's context, Windows Forms will be the subject. (Note: By "get" you mean great)

Comment: Indeed, "great" would be a more appropriate word than "get"!

Answer (score 1):

You can customise a windows form title bar by essentially rolling your own.
Set the "FormBorderStyle" to "None" - this removes the existing title bar.
Dock a thin black panel at the top of your form and add all the buttons/features you want to it - this will serve as your new title bar.

Once you have a form with your new title bar that you're happy with (let's call it CustomTitleBarForm) you can get all the forms that you want to use it to inherit from "CustomTitleBarForm" rather than the default "Form".

Comment: That method sure works! However, I'm trying to use a 3rd party theme file (.theme) for my Windows Forms project. Thanks anyways!